# Widlfly remote EJB-Lookup throws NoSuchEJBException: What's the problem?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, jndi

I don't get why my lookup throws a NoSuchEJBException: My Bean is deployed on wildfly. The admin-console shows that the server has registered the bean: It is listed as EJB under runtime/server/EJB, so I assume that it is deployed correctly. But I still do get a NoSuchEJB-Exception when I look it up remotely. I don't know where to look for a solution.

My EJB is deployed in a jar. The .jar-File is called "Markup2", the Bean is named "MarkupGeneratorBean". It is a remote and stateless session-bean.

Here the stacktrace:

```
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: EJBCLIENT000079: Unable to discover destination for request for EJB StatelessEJBLocator for "/Markup2/MarkupGeneratorBean", view is interface com.markupGenerator.MarkupGeneratorRemote, affinity is None
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:592)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(RemotingEJBClientInterceptor.java:56)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionPostDiscoveryInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(DiscoveryEJBClientInterceptor.java:114)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.NamingEJBClientInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(NamingEJBClientInterceptor.java:78)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:172)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:594)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:528)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:938)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:177)
at org.jboss.ejb-client@4.0.11.Final//org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:112)
at deployment.PTT2.war//com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.generateDocumentFromUrl(Unknown Source)
at deployment.PTT2.war//com.ptt.TestSessionGeneratorServlet.getRenderDocument(TestSessionGeneratorServlet.java:157)
at deployment.PTT2.war//com.ptt.TestSessionGeneratorServlet.doGet(TestSessionGeneratorServlet.java:70)
at javax.servlet.api@1.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
at javax.servlet.api@1.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@14.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
at io.undertow.core@2.0.13.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Here's the method of my serlvet that is doing the lookup:

```
private Document getRenderDocument() {
Document doc = null;
try {

  Context context = new InitialContext();


  MarkupGeneratorRemote mB = (MarkupGeneratorRemote) context.
      lookup("ejb:/Markup2//MarkupGeneratorBean!com.markupGenerator.MarkupGeneratorRemote");

  doc = Jsoup.parse(mB.generateDocumentFromUrl("http://localhost:8080/html-files/intro.html"));

  doc.getElementById("pretestform").html(qItem.getHtml() + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"let's go!\">");

} catch (NamingException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return doc;}
```

My pom.xml contains the following dependencies:

- jsoup:1.11.3 maven-war-plugin:3.0.0
- maven-plugin-api:3.0
- htmlunit:2.32
- serializer.2.7.2
- derbyclient:10.14.1.0
- wildfly-client.all:12.0.0.Final
- javax.persistence-api:2.2

My jndi.properties:

```
java.naming.provider.url = http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080
java.naming.factory.initial =  org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.factory.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming
```

my jboss-ejb-client.properties:

```
endpoint.name=client-endpoint
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=127.0.0.1
remote.connection.default.port=8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

Thank you very much in advance!!

EDIT: Here are the JNDI-Bindings of the Bean

```
java:global/Markup2/MarkupGeneratorBean!com.markupGenerator.MarkupGeneratorRemote
java:app/Markup2/MarkupGeneratorBean!com.markupGenerator.MarkupGeneratorRemote
java:module/MarkupGeneratorBean!com.markupGenerator.MarkupGeneratorRemote
java:jboss/exported/Markup2/MarkupGeneratorBean!com.markupGenerator.MarkupGeneratorRemote
ejb:Markup2/MarkupGeneratorBean!com.markupGenerator.MarkupGeneratorRemote
java:global/Markup2/MarkupGeneratorBean
java:app/Markup2/MarkupGeneratorBean
java:module/MarkupGeneratorBean
```

**EDIT:** In the meantime  I had been able to make successful remote EJB-invocations. Don't ask me how: I really don't know why I it did work. I switched to a CDI-workaround. After making a successful EJB-call on the same server in a different application, I wanted to try it again in the app that had the error above.  Later,  it stopped working in both apps after I had restarted the server - getting the same error as described above.

**UPDATE:** I was able to make remote EJB-invocations on another server. That means, that I must have messed something up on the original server unknowingly.

Comment: Can you redeploy the app then update your question to contain the entries that all come after these traces `JNDI bindings for session bean named 'XXXX' in deployment unit`?  They'll all start with `java:` and should be at least 6 per bean

Comment: you could use JNDI portable name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999407/javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-while-trying-to-lookup-abc-didnt-find-sub/53003723#53003723

Comment: @JGlass I added the JNDI-Bindings.

Comment: @MehranMastcheshmi I get a  javax.naming.NameNotFoundException when I try portable jndi names

Comment: Glad you got it figured out - sorry I am late on the reply!