# EJB 3.1 session beans not showing up in WebLogic 12c JNDI tree

Tags: java, weblogic12c, ejb-3.1

The following is an example of an EJB I've created for my webapp. In my WebLogic 12c server, the EJBs show up in java:global, but not in any other part of the JNDI tree. I think because of that, I'm having troubles looking up those EJBs.

Q1: Are the annotations I have on my classes sufficient and correct?
Q2: Should I be able to see my EJBs listed in java:app and java:module or anywhere else?

```
@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@Transactional
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
@Service("adminService")
public class AdminServiceImpl extends AbstractServiceImpl
    implements LocalAdminService, AdminServiceRemote
{
...
}
```

Here's my jndi.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=t3://localhost:7001
java.naming.security.principal=weblogic
java.naming.security.credentials=xyz
weblogic.rmi.clientTimeout=120000
```

Answer (score 1):

> Are the annotations I have on my classes sufficient and correct

you use too much annotation. when you annotate a bean with Stateless the default transaction will be CONTAINER and default TransactionAttribute will be Required.so you do not need these two annotations. also, you annotate the bean with @service. but you must not define a bean as Spring-managed bean and as EJB3 session. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.20.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ejb/interceptor/SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.html says:

> WARNING: Do not define the same bean as Spring-managed bean and as
>   EJB3 session bean in the same deployment unit. In particular, be
>   careful when using the  feature in combination
>   with the deployment of Spring-based EJB3 session beans: Make sure that
>   the EJB3 session beans are not autodetected as Spring-managed beans as
>   well, using appropriate package restrictions.

you also do not need Transactional annotation.

> Should I be able to see my EJBs listed in java:app and java:module or
>   anywhere else?

You just can see then java:global in JNDI tree of WebLogic. but you can use other namespaces for lookup. it depends on the location of the bean that lookups(application and module) and the location of the bean that you are looking. if you have any problem please check the location of your beans. you can have a look at the [javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'abc' didn't find subcontext 'abc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52999407/javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-while-trying-to-lookup-abc-didnt-find-sub/53003723#53003723) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Are you saying that I'll need to define a second class (an EJB class) for each service bean and basically have pass-through methods from the EJB to the service bean? If so, that's disappointing because I just got rid of those classes (pre-annotation usage) because I thought I could combine them into one with annotations. It was frustrating having to change the EJB class and adding another method whenever a new method was added to the service bean.

Comment: My pleasure.If you do not use component scan and define all spring bean in xml. You will not have to remove transactional and  service annotations. And you can inject spring bean in your ejb. But a bean must not be both a spring manged and an ejb bean.

Comment: Well, since as a part of upgrading the tech level of our project we've been trying to avoid XML files (we used to heavily use xdoclet) I guess two sets of classes is the way we'll have to go.

Comment: maybe you could use component-scan and set the base-package (to packages that you want to load in spring Context) in beanRefContext.xml. if you do not want to inject a bean with Autowire annotation into your session bean. you will not require to use SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor annotation.

Comment: So I divided it up and am now using an InitialContext to lookup the EJB, since I'm using them from an app outside of the server. I'm looking for "java:global.ifactory.ifactory-ejb-4.0.0.BomServiceBean!com.icumed.ifactory3.service.BomServiceRemote" which is exactly what I see in the JNDI console, but it's not being found. What now?

Comment: is your JNDI.properties file correct(connection information to JNDI service)?  https://blogs.oracle.com/luzmestre/how-to-connect-to-weblogic-datasource-from-a-java-client

Comment: I believe so. I've added it to the question. I'm not connecting to a remote data source, so I can't use everything in the link that you provided. BTW, I had forgotten to add wlthint3client.jar to the class path, but even after that, I'm still getting the same error, which is " javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: remaining name: (the complete JNDI name)"

Comment: I removed "java:global" from the jndi lookup name and got further, but am stuck at an exception that thrown while still looking up the EJB and ends with  "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
 at weblogic.rmi.internal.StubInfo.getEnvQueriedJNDITimeout(StubInfo.java:256)"